# How to check state of the contract after some time?

Tags: timestamp, scheduling, state

I am writing a contract where I need to check that if in 5 minutes no new token get purchased then the sale should be ended. What I mean exactly is that, lets say user A has purchased 100 tokens and now I want to see if no one purchase tokens in next 5 minutes then sale will be closed.

I am looking forward to gas efficient and automatic way.

can someone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
uint256 lastSaleTimestamp;

function isOpen() public view {
    // The sale is open if there haven't been any purchases or if the last
    // purchase was more than 5 minutes ago.
    return lastSaleTimestamp == 0 || now <= lastSaleTimestamp + 5 minutes;
}

function buy(...) external {
   require(isOpen(), "Sale is already closed.");
   lastSaleTimestamp = now;
   ...
```

Comment: but this will check only when a new purchaser will come. I need to do some more stuffs on sale closing, so I want the contract to check itself after 5 minutes that if no new purchaser has come then contract should execute saleclose() function and do the needful stuff.

Comment: Contract code is only executed as part of a transaction made be an externally owned account. It's hard to make a suggestion without knowing what "the needful stuff" is, but you can always have a `saleclose()` function that you can call after 5 minutes have passed.

Comment: in "needful stuff", I need to distribute funds to the existing token holders. so I want to check automatically, if there is a way, that if 5 minutes are passed then contract shall automatically do this?

Comment: If you want to actually do that stuff in the contract immediately, you'll need to run some code somewhere that monitors the blockchain and calls `salesclose()` at the right time. It's generally better, though, to delay doing the computation until you need to. (E.g. when existing token holders call `collect()` or something like that.)

Comment: thanks, can u also share your thoughts on this question? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/74728/how-to-select-a-wallet-address-by-the-token-number-he-owns